# For $X$ projective variety, $ X-Z(f) $ is isomorphic to an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I have to prove the following:

> Let $ K = \overline{K} $, consider $ X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n $ irreducible projective variety and $ f \in \mathbb{K} [x_0, ..., x_n] $ homogenous polynomial of degree $ d $. Prove that $ X-Z(f) $ is isomorphic to an affine variety.

My doubt is:

How to prove this result?

Is not it necessary to ask that $ X \cap Z (f) \neq \emptyset $?

*My idea was to use the Veronese application to see $ f $ as a linear function in a $ \mathbb{P}^N $ and so $ \mathbb{P}^N - Z (f) $ is an open affine.*

Comment: Isn't $X-Z(f)$ a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^N-Z(f)=\mathbb{A}^N$, after the Veronese?

Comment: Yes, it is, the argument is because $ v_d $ the Veronese mapping is mapping (isomorphism) between projective varieties, right?